# Embedding one WPF app into another - Resource file not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a requirement to embed one of our existing applications in our new one. I figured it would be quite easy, so I set made all the content of the origional application inside a UserControl "EmbeddedApp", with the theme applied in it's resources:

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.GUI.Window.EmbeddedApp"
             ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/App;component/GUI/Themes/Theme.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    ...all the app stuff...
</UserControl>
```

And the window for this as a stand alone app then just looked like this:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="App.MainWindow"
                      ...>
    <Window:EmbeddedApp/>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Nice and easy. I tested the "embedding" function in a test application in that project and it works fine.

However, I'm getting resource issues when I embed it into a "full" application like this. There's an exception "Exception: Cannot find resource named 'AccentSelectedColorBrush'. Resource names are case sensitive." on line:

```
<Rectangle Name ="container" Grid.Row="0"  Height="50"  Fill="Black" Stroke="{StaticResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}"/>
```

in the depths of the embedded App. How could this be happening if this is defined in a static resource in Theme.xaml? Why would it work fine in an "empty" application?

I tried adding the theme manually:

Now, Here AccentSelectedColorBrush is found for the rectangle. However, I'm still getting the error AccentSelectedColorBrush not found within EmbeddedApp, it's also White - which isn't as it's defined in Theme.xaml.I  can inspect it and the rectangle is resolving it fine:

[image]

If I remove the Theme.xaml, AccentSelectedColorBrush is not found.

**Edit:** I now have this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNewApp.Pages.Views.EmbeddedAppView"
             InheritanceBehavior="SkipAllNow"
             ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/App;component/GUI/Themes/Theme.xaml" />
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/App;component/GUI/Themes/Theme2.xaml" />-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel Height="447" Width="539">
        <Rectangle Width="100"  Height="100" Fill="{StaticResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}"/>
        <!--<App:EmbeddedApp Width="300"  Height="300"/>-->
        <Label Content="Texty Text"/>
        <TextBox Text="Some Text"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="Test"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Now, I'd expect the label and TextBox to be styled acording to Theme.xaml, but it's not doing that it's just using the default themes:

[image]

Yet in my "test" project, the Theme.xaml is applied fine:

[image]

So my conclusion is that:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/App;component/GUI/Themes/Theme.xaml" />
```

is not correct for an externally referenced project. I tried:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/App;component/GUI/Themes/Theme.xaml" />
```

but that has similar failure. It's definately finding it though, if I misspell and say put "Theme2.xaml" it comes up with an error. But for some reason it's not being applied properly.

**Edit2** I've tracked down the problem to how resources are referenced between user controls. I've decided to create a new question that focuses on the actual problem at hand:

["Sub" UserControl cannot find resource - how to get resources to "flow" down the visual tree (without placing it in App resources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488553/sub-usercontrol-cannot-find-resource-how-to-get-resources-to-flow-down-the)

Comment: Do you have `MergedDictionaries` defined anywhere? Did you just copy the resources from the original dictionary over into a resource dictionary in the project you're moving to, or is it separate all together and that's where your Source pack uri is getting involved in your mergeddictionaries spot? It's sounding like just an inheritance issue but difficult to troubleshoot without seeing more into the structure of things.

Comment: It's separate all together, hence why I'm trying to prevent this from inheriting parent styles using InheritanceBehavior="SkipAllNow", and instead load the Source pack uri from the other folder (though really, this is done by in the resources of the UserControl EmbeddedApp.xaml in the first code sample, so I shouldn't even need to do that).

Comment: I don't want the applications closely linked, so if the styles change in the referenced EmbededApp project I'll have to go and update things in the MyNewApp project - hence why I'm loading the style only in the UserControl that contains the EmbeddedApp.

Comment: But in your UserControl.Resources you are defining the ResourceDictionary path (via pack uri) as a declared `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` right?

Comment: I think I did that in order to try adding "Theme2.xaml". I've edited the "edit" code to show, and it behaves the same. Unless you are referring to the Theme.xaml resource dictionary itself? That does have a <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> for all reference dictionaries.

Comment: Ya like that, so you're saying the one you have commented out, isn't getting applied? If that UserControl is the one loaded into your existing then technically it would inherit from the parent app's theme.xaml by default, and your commented out one is maybe just a bad path, unless maybe I'm just missing something? +1 either way.

Comment: The commented out one is an intentional bad path so I could check that the Theme.xaml is a "good path", which it appears to be. The problem is, although that Theme.xaml is found by the compiler (unlike my testing of Theme2.xaml which doesn't exist) - it's not actually applied.